# How to get names present in both views?

Tags: sql, database

I have a very large view containing 5 million records containing repeated names with each row having unique transaction number. Another view of 9000 records containing unique names is also present.  Now I want to retrieve records in first view whose names are present in second view

```
select * from v1 where name in (select name from v2)
```

But the query is taking very long to run. Is there any short cut method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just using a `INNER JOIN`. This will return all rows that exist in both tables:

```
select v1.* 
from v1 
INNER JOIN v2
 on v1.name = v2.name
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

You can add the `DISTINCT` keyword which will remove any duplicate values that the query returns.

Answer (score 2):

use `JOIN`.

The `DISTINCT` will allow you to return only unique records from the list since you are joining from the other table and there could be possibilities that a record may have more than one matches on the other table.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    v1 a
        INNER JOIN v2 b
            ON a.name = b.name
```

For faster performance, add an index on column `NAME` on both tables since you are joining through it.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)